# Error while turning nested json into dataframe

Tags: r, json, parsing, flatten, jsonlite

I have a dtaframe with nested jsons in one column. I want to turn one of them into dataframe. That json is here: df[1,]$json and looks like this:

```
{"case": "payment: fraud checking", "params": {}, "answer": {"assistant_check": false}}
```

I try to do this:

```
library(jsonlite)

df[1,]$json %>% 
  fromJSON() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Why it happens? I guess because of "params": {}. How to solve it? Why i don't get this dataframe from dong that:

```
       case                 params    answer.assistant_check
payment: fraud checking      NA            FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If your json-column doesn't contain any array data, this will work for you (but eliminate `params`, if it is empty on all rows).

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

df$json %>%
    map_dfr(~unlist(jsonlite::fromJSON(.)))
```

Does that help you?